# How to use one checkbox out of a form post method

Tags: php, forms, post

i have a 10 forms with $_POST['submit'] with individual settings
every form beggins with

```
<form action="" method="POST">
```

and ends with

```
</form>
```

every form have is submit button
after all 10 forms i have a if statemate with a checbox values 0 and 1 , can i use it to all 10 forms ? because now it`s tell me : Notice: Undefined index

EDITED :

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$upgrade = security($_POST['upgrd']);
$amount = security($_POST['amount']);
if (security($_POST['cdn']) == 1) {
$money = $row['bank'] + $row['money'];
    } else {
$money = $row['money'];
}
```

this is a part of POST submit

and the code for the form is :

```
<?php
if (get_user_stopv($urow['id']) == 0) {
echo '
      <tr>
        <form action="" method="POST">
<td style="text-align:center;">Something here</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">' . $amount . '</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">7</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">
        <input type="hidden" name="upgrd" value="stopvote">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="' . $amount3 . '">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn-default" value="submit">
</td>
</tr>
</form>';
}
?>
```

all forms are like this exemple ...and at the end of all forms i have :

```
        <form action="" method="POST">
<?php
if (get_user_card($urow['id']) == 1) {
echo '
        <label class="pull-right">something here !&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        }
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="cdn" class="hidden" value="0" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="cdn" value="1"></label>
<br /><br />';
?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the notice.
If a checkbox isn't checked, its value doesn't come. 
You won't find it in $_POST.
You must do one of the following to check a checkbox for being checked:

1. `if(isset($_POST['cdn']))`
2. set up an `<input type="hidden" name="cdn" value="0">` *before* the checkbox. This way if a checkbox isn't checked — a zero will come. If it is checked — it will be overwritten by a "1".

---

And as for  your question:

It isn't clear from your code, but it seems to be there are several `<form>` elements on your page. When a form is submitted — it's just *one* form is submitted, not all forms on the page. One particular form. The one with the submit button you clicked.

If there are some more `<form>...</form>` blocks on your page — they are totally ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You want to send the values of multiple forms with one submit button, right?

I suggest to do it the following way:

The approach is based on jQuery's form serialization capabilities and event binding. What you need is a function which runs over all your forms, fetches their values and sends them, when you press the submit button.

You could use jQuery on client-side in your HTML for this.
jQuery provides a form serialization method serialize().

If you run `$('form').serialize()` on a page with multiple forms, all forms are serialized into one string. You could change it to include only certain forms by using their selectors, like so `$('#form1, #form2').serialize()`.

Write a function to aggregate the form values and send them via ajax:

```
    function sendFormValues() {

        // fetch form data and serialize it
        // this is where the magic happens :)
        var data = $('form').serialize();

        // show the serialized form data in the browser's console
        console.log(data);

        // jquery ajax POST 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "script.php",
            data: data,
        });
    }
```

Now you bind the event "submit button clicked" to the function "sendFormValues".

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#buttonSubmit").click(function(){
        sendFormValues();
    }); 
});
```

That's it! 
The values of all forms are send via an ajax post, when the submit button is pressed.

Please name your input fields properly to avoid name clashes.